Android 15 Boot Completed receiver is not able to launch a foreground service
I'm working on an Android app that was previously targeting Android 14 (API level 34) and utilized BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receivers to launch certain foreground services.
With the update to Android 15 (API level 35), I'm encountering errors due to the new restrictions on foreground service launches.
Any guidance or code examples on addressing these challenges would be greatly appreciated!
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

...

        <service
            android:name=".NetworkSpeedService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
            android:process=":network_speed_service" />

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

it's now throwing ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException

So this is intended behavior for Android 15, as per the behavior changes docs:

There are new restrictions on BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receivers launching foreground services. BOOT_COMPLETED receivers are not allowed to launch the following types of foreground services:

dataSync
camera
mediaPlayback
phoneCall
mediaProjection
microphone


As your service is registered as dataSync you won't be able to start it directly. There are documented alternatives here, but it depends on what you are trying to do. If your task is 3 minutes or less, shortService is a reasonable alternative.

My service type is shortService but getting the same ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79010058/getting-foregroundservicestartnotallowedexception-when-starting-a-foreground-ser
